# WiX/MSI: show error-dependent FatalError dialog

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

While installation is executed (server-side) I looked for a way to pass the result back to the client side. Especially the FatalError dialog should show a text depending on the reason of the failure. Since it seams not possible to pass the result via properties I stored it in a file.

Furthermore I replaced the FatalError dialog with my own dialog to display an error text depending on the error type.

My problem is, that I need to call a custom action before the dialog is displayed, that reads the result from the file.

Possible ways could be:

1) I register the custom action for the OnExit="error" event.
Question: I need to display the dialog afterwards. Maybe the custom action (C++) can show the dialog after it loaded the result from the file. But how?

2) My own FatalError dialog is registered for the OnExit="error" event (as usual).
Question: How can I call the custom action before the dialog is shown?

3) My own FatalError dialog is registered for the OnExit="error" event (as usual). It shows only a common error text. When the user clicks Next the custom action is executed and another specific error dialog is displayd. 
Problem: That bothers the user with pointless dialogues.

4) Any other idea ...?

Thanxs in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By means of 1) I could finally solve the problem. A custom action can display a dialog using MsiDoAction. Example:

```
MsiDoActionW(
    hInstall, //MSIHANDLE hInstall,
    L"MyFatalErrorDlg" //LPCWSTR szAction
);
```